# Does inheriting from an empty class increase that class's size?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, c++14

Given:

```
class A
{
};

class B : A // inherit from an empty class
{
    int * x;
};

class C
{
    int * x;
};
```

Is `sizeof(B) == sizeof(C)` according to standards?

While `sizeof(A) == 1`, the 1 is a "dummy" value because sizeof cannot return 0 in this case

According to standards, is the dummy value carried forward during inheritance from a non empty class.

On a practical note, the reason for the question is that I am using `void *` as a pointer to several classes, and it would be clearer if they all shared a base class, but this is performance critical code and adding one byte, would actually add 8 because of alignment with a 64 bit pointer in the child class.  That will significantly add to the total memory footprint and I will potentially have a large number of them.

Comment: You're describing [empty base optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo

Comment: Thank you, didn't know it had a name